# What is the time complexity of this nested loop code?

Tags: time-complexity

[image]

In this loop $j$ is dependent on $i$, and $j$ is executing like $n/2$, $n/2-1$, $n/2-2$, ... So does this sum up to $O(n\log n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just have one comparison when  $n$ is odd. So, the total complexity is (if we suppose $n$ is even, w.l.o.g.):

$$T(n) = \frac{n}{2} + (n +‌ (n-2) + (n-4) + ... + 2) $$
$$= \frac{n}{2} + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}i = \frac{n}{2} + 2\frac{\frac{n}{2}(\frac{n}{2}+1)}{2} = \Theta(n^2)$$

Comment: j is dependent on i, and j is executing like n/2 , n/2−1, n/2−2 ... 
isnt it so?

Comment: @HIRAKMONDAL How did you get $\frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: for i==0 how many times j loop executes?

Comment: @HIRAKMONDAL $n$ times.

Comment: okay..got it
i confused the printf with j

Comment: Thanks ..for your help

Comment: @HIRAKMONDAL Yes. indeed you tried to count the number of `printf`.